# creating one to many relation

Tags: mysql

i search a lot about this question in stackoverflow..there are same problem as me but didnt soloved my problem.
i created a table which has user in it..columns are somthing like this

```
uid 
username
name
family
....
```

now i need to create a black list which will store userid of blacklisted person.i dont know how to create this table because each person can have many black listed person then the black list table is somthing like this

```
uid = 1
blacklistid = 3

uid = 1
blacklist equal 4
```

then in this case i dont have any primary key which i think it's wrong.if i insert a primary key in auto incerement mode i will have a very big int and why should i need this primary key?for what reason?i asked someone and he told me maybe your design have a problem

then i need to know how to design this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key in the blacklist table is the combination of the user id and the blacklisted id.

```
User
  id
  name
  ...

Blacklist
  user_id
  target_id
```

The combination of user_id and target_id should be unique.

There is no need for an auto-incrementing id field.

Answer (score 1):

Ok what you are looking for is a 1 to many table but the twist is that you have a reference back to the original table, to get the details of the black listed user. So your user table looks like this with AppUserID being the PK to uniquely identify a user.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppUser](
    [AppUserID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  -- Pk for the user
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_APP_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [AppUserID] ASC)
) 
GO
```

Your black list table will have 0,1,n.. of blacklisted user for a particular AppUserId. You need the AppUserBlacklistID to uniquely reference a particular black listed user for a Current User.. in case you need to delete or update them. So you would use the AppUserBlackListId

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppUserBlackList](
    [AppUserBlackListID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AppUserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,                      -- Foreign Key to the AppUser table to identify the users black listed 'Users'
    [BlackListedAppUserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,           -- Foreign Key to the AppUser table to identify the user that is black listed
    [Reason] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_APP_ROLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AppUserBlackListID ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now create some Foreign key contraints

```
-- Foreign key to the users table. This is used to list all the black listed users for a particular user
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AppUserBlackList]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AppUserBlackList.AppUserID_AppUser] FOREIGN KEY([AppUserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AppUser] ([AppUserID])

-- This is a Foreign Key to the App user for the user that is black listed. It should also be unique in that one user can only blacklist another
-- User one time. 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AppUserBlackList]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AppUserBlackList.BlackListedAppUserID_AppUser] FOREIGN KEY([BlackListedAppUserID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[AppUser] ([AppUserID])
```

Now to be really tight on the design you could put in a unique constraint to show that a user cannot blacklist a person more than once and that they cannot black list themselves.

To get all the Blacklisted users for a particular user.. you join the 2 tables

```
Select AppUserBlackListID, AppUserID,BlackListedUserName
  from 
     AppUser auCurrentUser 
      Inner join AppUserBlackList auBl 
          on auCurrentUser.AppUserId = auBl.AppuserID 
      Inner join AppUser auBlackListedUserDetails 
          on auBL.BlackListedAppUserID =auBlackListedUserDetails.AppUserID
Where au.AppUserId = 10
```

So you need to join back to the user table to get the blacklisted user details

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but in my case best solution was having 2 composite primary key in one table

Comment: Ah no problems HiDd3N... Michiel answer was short and sweet and to the point but I just thought I'd give you a little bit more using a Primary key... instead of a composite :-)

Comment: is it better to use foreign key or using composite primary key??what do you think doiremik??

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want a many-to-many relationship: because one person can blacklist several others; and one person can be blacklisted by several others.

To implemented many-to-many you have a separate table with two columns (one column for the blacklister and the next column for their blacklist), for example:

```
1 2 // person 1 blacklists person 2
1 3 // person 1 also blacklists person 3
3 2 // person 2 is also blacklisted by person 3, as well as by person 1
```

If it's only one-to-many (one person can blacklist several others; and each person cannot be blacklisted by more than one other)

Comment: yeah i think you are right.then how should i create many to many..do i need primary key at all?